# JSON.parse() returning unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

So the issue I'm having is that when i try to call JSON.parse() on this string, i keep getting an unexpected token. It seems to keep escaping at maker and doesn't understand the []? If anyone could shed some light on this issue that would be greatly appreciated

```
var x = '[{
"db":"COLLECTIONS"
,"sisn":"1093041"
,"accession":"2011.285.01"
,"bowner":"Osgoode Township Historical Society and Museum"
,"title":"Wooden pattern for  foundry"
,"titlelink":"http://felix.minisisinc.com/ottawa/scripts/mwimain.dll/475/2/1/109    3041?RECORD&UNION=Y"
,"maker":[]
,"image":"[M3IMAGE]201128501.jpg"
,"bookmarked":0
,"refd":0
}]';

var result = JSON.parse(x);
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't work with newline characters in strings unless you use ES6 and backticks

Comment: Strings don't wrap around newlines. Replace the single quotes ' with backticks `

Comment: Why are you putting a literal JSON string in your code in the first place? Just put the object literal there with `var result = [{ ... }];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data provided parses just fine:

```js
var x = '[{' +
'"db":"COLLECTIONS"' +
',"sisn":"1093041"' +
',"accession":"2011.285.01"' +
',"bowner":"Osgoode Township Historical Society and Museum"' +
',"title":"Wooden pattern for  foundry"' +
',"titlelink":"http://felix.minisisinc.com/ottawa/scripts/mwimain.dll/475/2/1/109    3041?RECORD&UNION=Y"' +
',"maker":[]' +
',"image":"[M3IMAGE]201128501.jpg"' +
',"bookmarked":0' +
',"refd":0' +
'}]';

console.log(JSON.parse(x));
```

So the issue must be that (at least in your example) you are getting a syntax error for trying to assign a multi-line string. Multi-line strings cannot be assigned in that way. Here are some alternatives:

```js
// concatenate each line
var x = '[{' +
  '"db":"COLLECTIONS",' +
  '"sisn":"1093041"' +
'}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(x));

// escape each line
var x = '[{ \
  "db":"COLLECTIONS", \
  "sisn":"1093041" \
}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(x));

// template literal it (this snippet will not run in some browsers!)
var x = `[{
  "db":"COLLECTIONS",
  "sisn":"1093041"
}]`;
console.log(JSON.parse(x));
```

If using the "concatenate" technique, make sure to escape any single quotes that might be present in the string (i.e. `this is Marcelino\'s answer`).

If using the "escape" technique, the string cannot contain a backslash as the escaped backslash will not be properly handled by the `JSON.parse` (as least as far as I know, if anyone could clarify this, it would be great).

If using the "template literal" technique, make sure the [browsers that you are hoping to support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility) (or the js environment) in question has them available, or use a transpiler (i.e. Babel).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a backslash at the end of each line tells the JavaScript engine that the string will continue to the next line. Please try this:

```
var x = '[{ \
"db":"COLLECTIONS" \
,"sisn":"1093041" \
,"accession":"2011.285.01" \
,"bowner":"Osgoode Township Historical Society and Museum" \
,"title":"Wooden pattern for  foundry" \
,"titlelink":"http://felix.minisisinc.com/ottawa/scripts/mwimain.dll/475/2/1/109    3041?RECORD&UNION=Y" \
,"maker":[] \
,"image":"[M3IMAGE]201128501.jpg" \
,"bookmarked":0 \
,"refd":0 \
}]';

console.log(JSON.parse(x));
```